# Reason for the name "Ring of dual numbers"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, linear-approximation

The ring of dual numbers over a field $k$ is defined as the quotient

$$k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2.$$

I was reading [this question with an interesting answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56910/3416) about some of their basic properties and, if I understand correctly, this ring offers a way to produce approximations of the first order of non-analytic objects defined on $k$.

But the most important [ ;-) ] question remains open: Why are they called **dual** numbers?

Comment: Uninformed guess: because the elements have representations $a + \epsilon b$ as pairs of two ("dual") numbers.  Obviously this is not unique to this particular ring.

Comment: I agree with Ryan, but I'm not sure. And also I wonder, does $k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^{n+1}$ have a name? This ring classifies $n$-jets.